# Custom apptheme is not applied in custion tool bar

Tags: android

I am using custom action bar in my android app. I am trying to give it a custom theme but it is not working.

**app_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

`app_bar` is included in action_main.xml:

```
 <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            />
```

**styles.xml** has no action bar as parent:

```
<resources>
    <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In android manifest file I am using the above theme:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

In main activity :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        toolbar.setTitle(" Ringtone Control");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

But, I am not getting custom theme color. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this +Android Developers Pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/AV2ooBWY1iy), if you are using a `Toolbar` you need to specifically set the background color:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Only the default Action Bar will get the `colorPrimary` by default.

Comment: so it will only change background color.

Comment: Yep. If the background of your `Toolbar` is light and your theme is dark (or vice versa), you can also add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` or `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar"`to change things like text/icon color as explained in the post.